# How can I change pagination to show first last previous next

Tags: search

Hello how can I change the pagination in Magento that it shows links for previous site, next site, last site and first site?

What I want is that:

(1) 2 3 4 5 next last

first previous 1 (2) 3 4 5 next last

first previous 23 23 (25) 26 27 next last

first previous 3 4 5 6 (7)

I am using standard toolbar/pagination from Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento already shows previous and next images if needed.
So in order to add first and last links modify `app/design/fronend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/pager.phtml` and add this inside the `<?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>` statement.

```
<li>
    <a class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('first') ?>">
</li>
```

and inside the `<?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>` add this:

```
<li>
    <a class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('last') ?>">
</li>
```

Comment: Hi @Marius , in magent 2.3 ?

Comment: it would be great help, if you can tell me the same in magento 2.3.2

Comment: it should word the same for 2.3.2